# Spring BindingResult Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult 
nor plain target object for bean name 'billingInfoCommand' 
available as request attribute
```

My JSP looks like:

```
    <form:form commandName="billingInfoCommand" method="post" 
onsubmit="return checkVals()">
```

My controller looks like:

```
public class BillingInfoController extends FusionFormController {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private FieldAccessService fieldAccessService;

        public BillingInfoController(){
        setCommandClass(CommonCommand.class);
        setCommandName("billingInfoCommand");
    }

   protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request,Object command, Errors errors) throws Exception {

        CommonCommand commonCommand=(CommonCommand)command;
        HashMap<String,Object> refDataMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        refDataMap.put("billingTypes",this.getLookupValsAsMap("getBillingTypes"));
        Long stageId=commonCommand.getEmeaMain().getStageId();
        refDataMap.put("requiredFields",requiredFields);
        return refDataMap;
    }


  public Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request){
        BillingInfo billingInfoObj=null;
        Long cepWorkItemNo=null;
        CommonCommand billingInfoCommand=new CommonCommand();
        try{
         cepWorkItemNo=new Long(request.getParameter("cep_work_item_no"));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        }
        if(cepWorkItemNo==null){
           billingInfoObj=new BillingInfo();
        }else{
          billingInfoObj=(BillingInfo)domainService.getDomainObject(BillingInfo.class,cepWorkItemNo);
        }
        if(billingInfoCommand.getBillingInfo()==null)
           billingInfoCommand.setBillingInfo(billingInfoObj);
        if(billingInfoCommand.getEmeaMain()==null)
            billingInfoCommand.setEmeaMain(emeaMain);
        return billingInfoCommand;
   }
}
```

My Pojo class looks like:

```
public class BillingInfo {

    private Integer billingId;

    public Integer getBillingId() {
        return billingId;
    }
    public void setBillingId(Integer billingId) {
        this.billingId = billingId;
    }
}
```

**Note**

I have posted only relevant pieces of code here. I am not sure as to why am I getting mentioned error about IllegalStateException and some useful pointers would be appreciated.

Also, what are normal reason for getting `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name x available as request attribute` errors ?

**Full Stack Trace**

```
 - java.lang.IllegalStateException:
   Neither BindingResult nor plain
   target object for bean name
   'billingInfoCommand' available as
   request attribute
       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
   target object for bean name
   'billingInfoCommand' available as
   request attribute at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:148)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.resolveCssClass(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:404)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:380)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:90)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
   at
   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.globalecep.ap.billing_005finfo_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(billing_005finfo_jsp.java:1243)
   at
   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.globalecep.ap.billing_005finfo_jsp._jspService(billing_005finfo_jsp.java:363)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
   at
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
   at
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:565)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:493)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:965)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:600)
   at
   org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:137)
   at
   org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:177)
   at
   org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:756)
   at
   org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:881)
   at
   org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:473)
   at
   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.fusion.jsp.tab_005ftemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f2(tab_005ftemplate_jsp.java:1807)
   at
   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.fusion.jsp.tab_005ftemplate_jsp._jspService(tab_005ftemplate_jsp.java:307)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
   at
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
   at
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
   at
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:251)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1144)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:880)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:793)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
   at
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
   at
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
   at
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
   at
   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
   at
   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
   at
   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
   at
   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
   at
   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
   at
   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
   at
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Servlet Config Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">


    <bean id="apbillingInfoController" class="ap.BillingInfoController">
      <property name="queryService" ref="queryService" />
      <property name="domainService" ref="domainService" />
      <property name="formView" value="ap_billinginfo"/>
      <property name="validator" ref="apbillingInfoValidator" />
      <property name="fieldAccessService"  ref="fieldAccessService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="apbillingInfoValidator"  class="validator.ap.BillingInfoValidator">
           <property name="queryService" ref="queryService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="apcompanyBillingInfoController" class="ap.company.COMPANYBillingInfoController">
      <property name="commandName"   value="companyBillingInfoBean"/>
      <property name="commandClass"  value="command.ap.company.COMPANYCommonCommand"/>
      <property name="queryService" ref="queryService" />
      <property name="domainService" ref="domainService" />
      <property name="formView" value="ap_companybillinginfo"/>
      <property name="validator" ref="apcompanyBillingInfoValidator" />
      <property name="fieldAccessService"  ref="fieldAccessService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="apcompanyBillingInfoValidator"  class="validator.ap.company.COMPANYBillingInfoValidator">
        <property name="fieldAccessService"  ref="fieldAccessService"/>
       <property name="queryService" ref="queryService" />
    </bean>
      <property name="mappings">
        <props>
          <prop key="/ap_billing.htm">apbillingInfoController</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>

      <property name="mappings">
        <props>
          <prop key="/company_ap_billing.htm">apcompanyBillingInfoController</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `BillingInfoController`?

Comment: its my controller class, let me update the code to include that in there.

Comment: @skaffman-Have updated question and included `BillingInfoController` in there.

Comment: @SO Users : Is this question not clear ?

Comment: Also if someone can explain as to why this kind of errors occurs from explanation point of view than also it would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=37068

Comment: @Jeremy - Yes, I have looked at it and am not breaking the Spring Call Structure and so am not sure as to why am I getting this error and so have opened question here at SO to get some useful feedback and understanding.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: Updated with full stack trace.

Comment: @Rachel: Can't see anything wrong in it. Are you sure you don't override controller's command name somewhere (e.g. in XML config)?

Comment: Which other methods are you overriding in the controller hierarchy?  Which controller class is FusionFormController coming from?  Actually, I don't see either in the stack trace...is your dispatcher servlet controller bean mapped to the right view?

Comment: Can you paste the dispatcher servlet controller/view wiring and mapping?

Comment: @axtavt: Yes. I am not overriding controller's command name in xml config.

Comment: My dispatcher servlet is mapping to correct view also FusionFormController is internally implementing SimpleFormController

Comment: I would print some text from within the formBackingObject method to make sure it is getting called like you think.

Comment: Yes. I have done that and it is getting called as expected.

Comment: Are your other referenceData objects present in the view if you take out the command object reference in the view?

Comment: @Matt: I did not got your point here ?

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring when the command object is being referenced in the JSP/view.  If that is the case, then take out the reference to that command object, and assert that the other object you added are present, like billingTypes.

Comment: Have you gotten any resolution to your problem Rachel?

Comment: Hi John, not exactly but it appears that I was pointing to wrong database table and so was getting bindingResult error also I checked on the jsession values and it were different for my request, actually I have page url which am hitting as currently the application is in the development phase and so somehow session is not getting set properly.

Comment: Also other observation was that from JSP bean of other package was being called and my package bean was not actually called as i have two packages, one for ap and other one for company and while I was hitting ap billing link somehow from the jsp company billing beans where called via EL and so that was also the reason for the error message. I should have made sure that bean are properly referenced in the jsp. Also, is there any difference between commenting the code and removing the code in jsp ?, i know this is kind of wierd but if i comment code than error was popuping up and not otherwise.

Comment: Commenting and removing has the same effect.  Compiled (byte) code does not contain any comments.

Comment: But the wierd par is that if I have comments in jsp page than am getting errors and if I delete commented code all together than application seems to be working fine, I am short on explanation as to why this thing is happening but that is true.

Comment: Oh, the jsp is a different subject.  You generally want to avoid java in JSP's (considering you are mantaining it you probably have no other choice).  In that instance whatever works I would suggest is the best.  I am not 100% sure if a jsp compiler accounts for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself occurs when your jsp's are rendered.  I am assuming you have a jsp with possibly a tag like (spring:bind will cause the same issue)

```
<form:form modelAttribute="billingInfoCommand">
...
</form:form>
```

When it renders the jsp, it looks for a bean called billingInfoCommand in your request scope and makes it available for jstl expressions (among other things).  When there exists no object in the request scope, the exception youre seeing is thrown.

Edit:

Thats good to see you didnt get any errors from removing all your code.  Next thing now, try looking at the request scope directly.

```
<div>The request scope is: ${requestScope}</div>
<div>The command is: ${requestScope.billingInfoCommand}</div>
```

If you see something like

The request scope is: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver......
   The command is:

Then the your bean is not actually in the request scope.  The next thing you have to look at is where does the backing object get put into the request scope.  First thought is that formBackingObject method may have something to do with getting it into the request.

Comment: But in my case I have `billingInfoCommand` in request scope and so am not sure why am I getting this error, any clue ?

Comment: Also from jsp my call is `<form:form commandName="billingInfoCommand" method="post" onsubmit="return checkVals()">`

Comment: I was saying to remove that <form/> (comment it out), and try to load the page.  Then the reference to that object would be gone, and potentially the page would load.  You would then know if your command object was getting lost in the controller before the view was shown (showForm(...)), etc.

Comment: @Matt: Tried commenting out the `form tag` and still am getting the same BindingResult Error Message.

Comment: Two questions, 1.  the form:form you were referring to, is that in billingInfo.jsp, 2.  If you remove all html (except maybe the headers) does the problem still persist

Comment: `Its in billing_info.jsp` and no, I do not have any error message if I remove all the html code except the header information. But what can be inferred upon this observation ?

Comment: `An error occurred while processing the request: Unknown entity: com.att.globalecep.domain.ap.BillingInfo` I have BillingInfo in the package structure but still am getting this error message, any clue ?

Comment: You are right, am getting `The request scope is: org.apache.commons.el.ImplicitObjects$2@91772
The command is: `

Comment: Try putting a System.out.println("Setting the command object"); In public Object formBackingObject().  And look to see if thats getting printed out.  If not, maybe annotate that method with @Override.

Comment: What you want to see is 'The command is com.att.globalecep.domain.ap.BillingInfo@235214' (or something similar)

Comment: Here is a reference to the SimpleFormController method execution sequence: http://users.tpg.com.au/fuzziman/blog/SimpleFormControllerCheatSheet_1.2.pdf

Comment: I am setting commandObject using ` public BillingInfoController(){
  setCommandClass(CommonCommand.class);
  setCommandName("billingInfoCommand");

 }`

Comment: thanks matt.  I use the annotated controllers.  Havent touched the older spring stuff in a while.  @Rachel, what url are you hitting ap_billing.htm or company_ap_billing.htm?

Comment: Basically, am setting in the constructor of the BillingInfoController

Comment: No, you are setting the command name and class there.  You are actually setting the command in formBackingObject.  When you submit a form, binding will occur on the object with that command name and will be cast with that class.

Comment: @John: I am hitting `ap_billing.htm`

Comment: Rachel, that only tells what the common command will be for that class, it doesnt physically set the command bean in the request scope.

Comment: @Matt: Are you pointing to this `billingInfoCommand.setBillingInfo(billingInfoObj);` ?

Comment: Rachel, just a stab in the dark.  But can you annotate the   formBackingObject method as @Override   public Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request){       Then restart the server and see what you get

Comment: @John: I was under the impression that am setting command class in the constructor, actually this code is of my colleague who has left and I have to work further on it and am trying to understand it.

Comment: No.  The object that you return from formBackingObject is your command; is the JSP form command; is referenced in the request by the command name.

Comment: @John: What would be benefits of doing so ? How would it help us to get rid to the BindingResult errors at hand ?

Comment: @Matt: You are right, command is being returned from the FormBackingObject but am not sure as to how it is getting set in the request ?

Comment: Again it has been a while since used a SimpleFormController, but the method dispatch itself may not invoke your classes formBackingObject, instead it could be invoking the SimpleFormController.  By annotating it with @Override it may invoke the method you want.

Comment: Did @Override but still am getting same bunch of BindingResult Errors

Comment: Is the formBackingObject method being called?  I said earlier, you can put the  System.out.println in to some debugging.  If you do see it there, try doing something like request.setAttribute("billingCommandInfo", new Object()); in that method

Comment: Yes, formBackingObject is being called and I have some sysout's there to check the flow and its going in there.

Comment: Take out the validator if you can.  Then re-run/test.

Comment: Did you try to directly set it into the HttpServletRequest?

Comment: re-ran the test without validator and it still gives same BindingResult error messages

Comment: @John: request attribute directly into httpservletrequest ?

Comment: And, which methods are being overridden in FusionFormController?

Comment: @John: How do I set attribute directly in the httpservletrequest ?

Comment: Rachel try.  request.setAttribute("billingCommandInfo", new Object());   Do that in the formBackingObject method right before returning.

Comment: Did that but still command is coming up blank

Comment: You have to be losing the request somewhere. If you reference the object just as ${billingCommandInfo} is it still blank?

Comment: Even am curious to know now what is happening. Yes that is correct

Comment: This would be my last kind of shot in the dark.  Try request.getSession().setAttribute("billingCommandInfo", new Object());  Then in the jsp try ${sessionScope.billingCommandInfo}.  If that works then you are either forwarding or redirecting from that controller for whatever reason.

Comment: Nope. Still command is showing up as blank.

Comment: Are you still online John and Matt ?

Comment: You say it deffinately is calling that method, so I have to believe you, but the only way that can actually happen, is if you invalidate the session each request (which I doubt you do).  It just seems as if that method is never called.

Comment: Hmm...i am printing the sysout's for the formBackingObject methods and it is being printed on the console.

Comment: The problem here, is that request.getSession() returns the entire session for the current browser.  This persists across all requests (and responses).  When you update the session, no matter what you should see it in all jsp's and controllers.  Thats why I say it is odd you are not getting it to work

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, there is something fishy going on which is not evident to my naked eyes.

Comment: Anyways John thanks for your valuable input, i will try to work more on this and see what is the actual issue going on in here. I will leave from office now but again thanks for yours and Matt's Inputs. Will post comment or solution if I get it fixed by tonight.

Comment: Ok good luck.  One thing you can try to look at is see what the JSessionID is when you do mutiple requests to the same url on the same browser.  They should all be the same.

Comment: Ok. I will continue working on this later today and see but I want to make sure that normally what is the reason for this kind of errors in spring ?

Comment: I have seen working with weblogic, that certain weblogic configuration would cause any http request to lose the session.  Not saying thats the case here but identifying where the loss is could help.

Comment: So loosing out on session could be the only reason for such bindingresult errors ?

Comment: Not the only reason, but if you are losing the session some how that deffinately is a good place to start.  The actual issue at this point can be anything :/

Comment: Actually I have googled a lot for this kind of issue and have not got anything worthwhile regarding the issue and so am curious to know as too what would be the issues when this kind of error pops up, basically things to look for in such situations ?

Comment: Oh ok so there is no specific areas to look for while debugging such an issues, would that a correct statement ?

Comment: Well a clear sign that you are losing your session is if the jsessionId for each request is different.   But that is just a blind guess really.

Comment: oh ok so basically, it is just trial and error methodology to fix this type of bugs ;)

Comment: Unfortunately.  What you may get out of this is a vast knowledge about how spring-mvc and servlets work :)

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to find out what would I learn once this is fixed :), anyways I will leave now and thanks for your help and guidance, really appreciate your inputs on this.

Comment: Spring 2.x's form controller hierarchy is simple in some cases, but can be enormously complex in others.  Either way, I think this is NOT a complex situation, and that the best option would be to create a plain SimpleFormController bean mapping that works with a blank view.  After that I would create my own controller that extends SimpleFormController, and continue on in that fashion until I have a working form.  If you have other controller's working under this context already, then the session shouldn't be an issue, and I would move to re-creating the controller.

Comment: @Matt: That is my last resort if nothing works out then.

Comment: @John: I am getting different Jsession id for each request and so will it be fair enough to say that we are loosing out our session between requests.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an incorrect controller/view wiring.  I say that because I see no reference to the BilingInfoController in your stack trace.  There should at least be a reference to that controller for the handleRequest/Internal to load the formBackingObject.

Comment: i have updated my question with the config file which has the controller and view mapping, can you have a look at it ?

Comment: Stacktrace is correct - `DispatcherServlet.render()` is called after controller returned `ModelAndView`.

Comment: @axtavt - So what could be the possible reason of having such an error message, any idea ?

Comment: @Rachel: I don't know, but since stacktrace is fine the only possible reason I can imagine is a mismatch between controller's command name and command name in JSP. I see you have 2 controllers with different command names, are you sure their JSPs also have the different command names?

Comment: @axtavt: I have same commandname in controller and jsp and yes their jsp's have different command names but right now am just trying to get ap page working fine without considering company page and am getting this error message on ap page itself, hope am making my self bit clear here...normally what should the debug sequence to get rid of this kind of bugs ?

Comment: @axtavt: Quick questions should the command name in xml be same as the prop keys or they can be different ? Also i have do not defined explicitly command name for `apbillinginfocontroller` and have `formview` name instead so they all refer to one thing ?

Comment: And if you change your formView to "ap_billing"?

Comment: My debug sequence would be to write Spring context tests to assert that the controllers and wirings are correct, and then visually test the view with the web server

Comment: @Matt: Tried doing that but it does not make any difference and am getting the same BindingResult error message.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Either there is something that I don't see in your current pasted code, or you have a problem somewhere in your super class or something.  At this point, I don't have anything else to add.

Comment: @Matt: Ok. Thanks for this much info, seems like there is something going on internally, I will spend some time on it and share some updates tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the bind object or the Display object in the request using

and this should be placed before the Binding Object  is used or before any include jsp tags
as below