# Getting Error in Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting following error....

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'course' available as request attribute**
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at
```

Model Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="course" ,schema = "practise5")
public class Course implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private int id;

     @Column(name="Name")
        private String Name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="courseSet")
    private Set<Person> personSet;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public Set<Person> getPersonSet() {
        return personSet;
    }

    public void setPersonSet(Set<Person> personSet) {
        this.personSet = personSet;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addCourse",method= RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addCourse(@ModelAttribute("course") Course course, Model model)
{

    courseServise.addcourse(course);

    return "redirect:addEmployee";
}
```

Jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="course" action="addCourse" method="POST">
<form:input path="CourseName" id="course" required="required"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

............................................................................................................................................................

```
<context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/" mapping="/**" />


<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.spring.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: please explain when you are getting that error and what is the stacktrace

Comment: Need stacktrace  to understand problem.

Comment: I am just storing  value in database using spring mvc and hibernate.There is a input of course name and using courseServise i am addin it in database. Do not know about stacttrace.

Comment: Did you define the beans in the spring application context?

Comment: Andreas Hartmann yes i define it.

Comment: Show your controller code which renders form jsp

Answer (score 1):

I just add the following code in my controller...

Second thing is that you have to first redirect your **index.jsp** file to some other file...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("a") A a, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) 
{

    return "addEmployee";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't match the correct URL in your JSP file.
Change this line on your JSP file :

```
<form:form commandName="course" action="addCourse" method="POST">
```

For:

```
<form:form commandName="course" action="/addCourse" method="POST">
```

---

Else, you can change your mapping on your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addCourse",method= RequestMethod.POST)
```

For:

```
@RequestMapping(value="addCourse",method= RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126153/spring-bindingresult-error) post, error might occur while loading the jsp itself, and
more over binding might fail for below reasons

> The binding results can be examined via the BindingResult interface,
>   extending the Errors interface: see the getBindingResult() method.
>   Missing fields and property access exceptions will be converted to
>   FieldErrors, collected in the Errors instance, using the following
>   error codes:

```
> Missing field error: "required" 
> Type mismatch error: "typeMismatch"
> Method invocation error: "methodInvocation"
```

so check any type mismatches or field you might have missed, as i had faced this issue personally